# java command hitting ARG_MAX limit in RH linux

Tags: java, linux, operating-system, redhat, argmax

Our application is generating a huge java command as there are 700+ jar entries in the classpath that we supply. The result is:

```
java": error=7, Argument list too long
    at oracle.jbo.dt.jdevx.deployment.SdoDeployListener.deployed(SdoDeployListener.java:547)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.hook.DeployerListenersHandler$HookDeployerListener.deployed(DeployerListenersHandler.java:418)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.fwk.ListenerSupport.fireDeployed(ListenerSupport.java:215)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.common.AbstractDeployer.deploy(AbstractDeployer.java:162)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.common.AbstractStatefulDeployer.deploy(AbstractStatefulDeployer.java:130)
```

This java command is generated internally by a Jdeveloper tool so we do not have control over the jars that we supply in the classpath. The java command is hitting 131072 char limit set in the /usr/include/linux/limits.h file as the command has 135942 length.

```
/usr/include/linux/limits.h
#define ARG_MAX       131072    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */
```

How I can set the higher limit for ARG_MAX? I cannot set it at OS level as this build may run on different machines.